# How to have the thumbnail cropping tool working

Tags: thumbnails, cropping

I've been using wordpress (and developing on it) for years now, but never be really able to use the drop tool. So I try to ask here...

If I crop a thumb,

[image]

I see the right cropping in the media editing window,

[image]

but then I don't get that cropped image if I ask for the thumb (even in frontend).

[image]

Why?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function, for example. Change for your needs and put on yours theme function.php file.

```
add_image_size('Special', 545, 365, true);
add_image_size('Mobile', 291, 197, true);
add_image_size('Ipad', 217, 147, true);

add_image_size('Block', 253, 172, true);
add_image_size('Single', 602, 358, true);
add_image_size('Small', 75, 49, true);
add_image_size('Block-height', 253, 245, true);
add_image_size('Related', 183, 124, true);
add_image_size('Big_one', 393, 266, true);
```

On frontend, inside on loop just call for example:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('Mobile'); ?>
```

On existing images you need to reupload, recheck. This function is accepted on new upload images.

Comment: Thank you, I already use that code but still I can't get what I want. I just added images to the original post to better explain

Comment: The problem with the above code is that this will make 9 (all the above images) + 3 (the default thumbnail, medium, large) = 12 images per every single image you upload, so if you upload 100 images, WordPress would generate 12,000 images based off that. Theoretically the above cropping tool works only on that images (and optionally the other generated images).

Comment: Yes that's not a good thing. Though, that's not the way to solve my problem and, as I see, a problem of really a lot of people. Basically, it seems that tool simply   doesn't work even in 3.8.1

Comment: In my case there is specific use for images, on my project i dont need to scale and quality lost for images.